# Mountain bike saddle rails extension

Tags: saddle, rails

Please give me the benefit of your expertise.

I'm 6'3" (190 cm) tall and, though I have the largest sized-mountain bike available I'm bent over as I cycle because I can't push back my saddle any more on its rails.

Is there any way that to remedy this situation?

Comment: There are seat posts with "setback" which is a measurement of how far further back they are from the vertical.  However your description of "I'm bent over" doesn't sound like a saddle too far forward, which would be "the handlebars are too near my knees"   Instead it sounds like your seat is too far above your handlebars?    Can you please add a photo of yourself on the bike from the side, in a normal riding posture?

Comment: A longer stem might help!

Comment: I suspect what you really want to do is change your handlebar position.  This likely involves changing some stem components.  (Many bikes are shipped with the handlebar unreasonably low, because that looks "meaner" on the display floor.)

Comment: James - we're still waiting on further information from you.  Use the edit link to add more.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to get a proper fit at a bike shop, that way they can tell exactly where you are stretched that you shouldn't be. It could be a simple fix or a more complex one.

The confusing part of your question is, if you moved the seat back further wouldn't you then need to be bent over further to reach the bars? Maybe the solution is moving the seat forward on the rails if your too folded up..

Or look into a lay back or offset seat post or stem size/angle adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

The seat tube is generally fixed at 17 deg for all bike sizes.  Because you can adjust saddle height, the relation between bottom bracket and saddle does not depend upon bike size.  However, if your femur is very long in relation to your tibia,  I could see how you might need to move your saddle back.

It is worth noting that most riders are able to temporarily exert more power by moving forward on the saddle ("riding on the rivets").  Having your saddle too far back precludes that position.

Comment: Seat tube angles range from 70° to 75°. While angles of 73°±1° are most common, they're not *generally fixed*.

Comment: Minor nitpick - Seat tube and head tube angles are measured from the horizontal, not the vertical.

Comment: Speaking if exceptions, my Cannondale Scalpel has a seat tube that heads up straight from the bottom bracket for a bit before bending back.  Which means the angle does depend upon the seat height.  Even so, in the specs the seat angle is fudged to be a constant.